# insert stylesheet link into multiple index.html

Tags: html, bash, sed

I have a folder in a ftp with a hundred of subfolders, each have it's own index.html

I want to add a `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://subdomain.domain.fr/vad/client/build/iconfont.css">`

in each index.html

The subdomain is variable and can be captured from another stylesheet link ex :

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://subdomain.domain.fr/vad/client/build/theme.css">`

I tried this :

```bash
find . -type f -name index.html -exec sed -i 's/<link rel="stylesheet" href="https:\/\/\(*\).domain.fr\/vad\/client\/build\/theme.css">/<link rel="stylesheet" href="https:\/\/\1.domain.fr\/vad\/client\/build\/theme.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="https:\/\/\1.domain.fr\/vad\/client\/build\/iconfont.css">/g' {} \;
```

With capturing and copy groups but it's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ease and readability, change the delimiter from `/` to let's say `#` You also have to escape real dots in search pattern…

```bash
sed -i 's#<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://\(*\)\.domain\.fr/vad/client/build/theme\.css">#<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://\1.domain.fr/vad/client/build/theme.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://\1.domain.fr/vad/client/build/iconfont.css">#g'
```

From there, I can see there's a mistake in your regexp capturing group… You wrote `\(*\)`, but I suspect you mean `\(.*\)` :) (otherwise, you where trying to capture nothing …or by chance opening parenthesis only…)

---

Now, it's look like you are replacing one word with another one, in order to change the CSS file? As it's appearing in a specific kind of line, you can perform a simple replacement in line matching that pattern ;)

```bash
sed -i '/\<link rel="stylesheet" href="https:\/\/.*\.domain\.fr\/vad\/client\/build/s#theme#iconfont#'
```

Comment: Sed is not a HTML parser. Don't use regex/sed

Comment: Sure sed is not a HTML parser mister @GillesQuenot & I wasn't answering to "how to use sed as HTML parser", instead "doing a substitution with sed but don't understand what i'm doing wrong". Sorry for the offense.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Perl` and a [`Mojo::DOM`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM) `HTML` Parser to edit your `HTML`:

```
use strict; use warnings;
use Mojo::DOM;

# Slurp the whole HTML as string    
my $html = join "", <>;

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new($html);

# Fetch domain name
$_ = $dom
     ->find('link[href][rel="stylesheet"]')
     ->map(attr => 'href')
     ->last;
my ($domain) = m|^https?://([^/]+)/|
    or die "No match https?!\n";

# Find/append
$dom
    ->find('head > link[href][rel="stylesheet"]')
    ->last
    ->append(
        "\n" . 
        '<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://' .
        $domain .
        '/build/iconfont.css" />'
    );

# Render
print "$dom";
```

### Output

Example of one file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="fr" xml:lang="fr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<link href="https://subdomain.domain.fr/build/theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://subdomain.domain.fr/build/iconfont.css" rel="stylesheet">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
  POUET
</body>
</html>
```

### Usage

First test the script against some files without `sponge`.

Then, if tests are satisfactory:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar # enable recursion **

for h in **/*.html; do
    perl Mojo::DOM.pl "$h" | sponge "$h"
done
```

Comment: How would I do that if the subdomain is variable from one index to another ?

Comment: At least I can insert a new node and edit the subdomain by hand of the 170 indexes

Comment: Maybe you could read the API to figure it out. Maybe I'll take time to go deeper later...

Comment: Added full featured code.